Python Script To Monitor RASPI GPIO
I'd like write a Python script to run on on a Raspberry Pi (3B+) to monitor several GPIO pins for an external button press.
When a button is pressed (shorted to 0 volts), I would like another GPIO output to trigger a Sainsmart relay card, to trigger a relay momentarily, and send an email when this occurs.
I have this working for ONE input and ONE output.  Here's that code:
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import smtplib

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setwarnings(False)

# Set GPIO 17 to act as input, and set it's state...this is the pins for the button
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
# Set GPIO 2 as an output, this will trigger the Sainsmart relay card 
GPIO.setup(2,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(2,GPIO.HIGH)

while True:
# monitor the status of the INPUT GPIO 17, when button is preessed, trigger GPIO 2 OUTPUT
    input_state = GPIO.input(17)
    if input_state == False:
        print('Button Pressed')
        GPIO.output(2, GPIO.LOW)
        print ("RELAY FIRED")
        time.sleep(1.0);
        GPIO.output(2, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        # initialize connection to our email server we will use  here
        smtp = smtplib.SMTP('server.com', port='587')
        smtp.ehlo()  # send the extended hello to our server
        smtp.starttls()  # tell server we want to communicate with TLS encryption
        smtp.login('user@server.com', 'passwordhere')  # login to our email server
        # send our email message 'msg' to our boss
        smtp.sendmail('user@server.com', ['recip1@domain1.com', 'recip2@domain2.com'], "Content Of Email")
        smtp.quit()  # finally, don't forget to close the connection
        time.sleep(0.5)
GPIO.cleanup()

How can I add additional INPUT and OUTPUT GPIO's to this?  Fairly new with Python.  Worst case, I'll just write eight scripts and run them all, all the time.

Right now, you have one pin each and store them in one place each.
If you want to use multiple pins (possibly for multiple purposes) a data structure such as an array would come in handy.
Arrays can hold multiple elements and allow you to easily access them sequentially.
Here's an example, based on your code:
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import smtplib

# Setup
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

# Define your input and output GPIO pins
input_pins = [17, 27]  # Replace with your input GPIO numbers
output_pins = [2, 3]   # Replace with your output GPIO numbers

# Setup GPIO inputs and outputs
for pin in input_pins:
    GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

for pin in output_pins:
    GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.HIGH)

try:
    while True:
        # Loop through each input pin and check its state
        for i, input_pin in enumerate(input_pins):
            input_state = GPIO.input(input_pin)
            if input_state == False:
                print(f'Button {i + 1} Pressed')
                GPIO.output(output_pins[i], GPIO.LOW)
                print(f"RELAY {i + 1} FIRED")
                time.sleep(1.0)
                GPIO.output(output_pins[i], GPIO.HIGH)
                time.sleep(0.5)

                # Send an email
                smtp = smtplib.SMTP('server.com', port='587')
                smtp.ehlo()
                smtp.starttls()
                smtp.login('user@server.com', 'passwordhere')
                smtp.sendmail('user@server.com', ['recip1@domain1.com', 'recip2@domain2.com'], f"Button {i + 1} Pressed - Content Of Email")
                smtp.quit()
                time.sleep(0.5)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # Clean up GPIO on CTRL+C exit
    GPIO.cleanup()
finally:
    # Clean up GPIO on normal exit
    GPIO.cleanup()

This example loops through the array of input pins and checks each one individually.
If you'd want to send emails to different recipients, a dict (different data structure) might be better suited.

Assuming Python arrays zero based (first item is 0, second is 1)...So in this code, input[1] will trigger output[1]?
Thanks for the quick reply!

Yes, exactly :)
